In Swift, how to send network requests upon tap such that each request has a few seconds delay in between?
I have created this simple example to show the issue.
I have 4 buttons for upvoting, favouriting, flagging, and hiding. User can tap any button whenever they like and as many times as they want. However, the network request which is sent after the tap must always have a minimum delay of 2 seconds in between. Also, all requests must be sent in order.
For example, suppose a user taps "upvote" 0.1 seconds after tapping "flag". The flagging request should be sent immediately after tapping "flag", and 2 seconds after receiving the response from the flag request, the upvote request should be sent.
The following seems to work but sometimes, it doesn't obey the 2 second delay and sends multiple requests at the same time without any delay in between. I am having a hard time figuring out what's causing this. Is there a better way to do this? Or what's the problem with this?
import UIKit
import SnapKit

extension UIControl {
    func addAction(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event = .touchUpInside, _ closure: @escaping()->()) {
        addAction(UIAction { (action: UIAction) in closure() }, for: controlEvents)
    }
}

let networkDelay = TimeInterval(2)
var requestWorkItems = [DispatchWorkItem]()
var lastRequestCompletionTime: Date?

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        view.addSubview(stack)
        stack.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        ["UPVOTE","FAVORITE","FLAG","HIDE"].forEach { title in
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.addAction { [weak self] in
                
                let urlString = "https://example.com/api?action=\(title)"
                
                self?.scheduleNetworkRequest(urlString: urlString)
            }
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
            button.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
            stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    
    }
    
    func scheduleNetworkRequest(urlString : String) {
        let workItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            self?.sendNetworkRequest(urlString: urlString)
        }

        requestWorkItems.append(workItem)
            
        if Date().timeIntervalSince(lastRequestCompletionTime ?? .distantPast) > networkDelay {
            scheduleNextWork(delay: 0)
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleNextWork(delay : TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            if let workItem = requestWorkItems.first {
                requestWorkItems.removeFirst()
                print("Tasks remaining: \(requestWorkItems.count)")
                workItem.perform()
            }
        }
    }

    func sendNetworkRequest(urlString : String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else if let _ = data {
                print("Completed: \(urlString) at: \(Date())")
            }
            lastRequestCompletionTime = Date()
            self?.scheduleNextWork(delay: networkDelay)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}


Loon into “debounce”

You need to queue the requests onto a buffer, and follow each request with a delay before drawing another request from the buffer. This is very easy using the Combine framework. I wouldn't bother trying to build this with dispatch queue if I were you; it's just reinventing the wheel.

When you say “the network request which is sent after the tap must always have a minimum delay of 2 seconds in between”, what precisely do you mean? In between what? Two seconds between the tap and the network request? Or two seconds between the network request and the network request that is to be generated for another tap? I.e., tap three buttons quickly and send the first network request immediately and then the subsequent two network requests at an interval of one every two seconds?

Sorry for not being clear. I meant the last one: tapping three buttons quickly sends the first network request immediately, then waits 2 seconds to send the second request, then waits 2 seconds to send third request.

Do you mean you want 2 seconds between receiving a response from the previous request and sending the next request? Or do you not care about when a response is received, and just want 2 seconds between the sending of every two requests?

@Sweeper ideally between reaching a response from previous request and sending the next request.

I would use an AsyncStream to record the URLs, and use a Task to consume the stream, waiting 2 seconds in between.
// add these properties to the view controller
var task: Task<Void, Error>?
let (stream, continuation) = AsyncStream.makeStream(of: URL.self)

In the button's action, add a URL to the continuation:
button.addAction { [weak self] in
    self?.continuation.yield(URL(string: "https://example.com/api?action=\(title)")!)
}

and initialise task in viewDidLoad like this:
task = Task {
    for await url in stream {
        do {
            print("Sending request to \(url)")
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            // do something with data & response
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        } catch let error as CancellationError {
            throw error
        } catch {
            // handle network errors...
        }
    }
}

Lastly, call task?.cancel() in deinit.

While this does work, unfortunately Task and 'AsyncStream' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer. Is there a way to get this working from iOS 11?

@sudoExclamationExclamation Are you sure you have users running iOS 11? That's released 7 years ago! I don't want to get my hands on GCD again, so I guess you'll have to wait for other answers.

Yes, it's for my existing hacker news app which has been compatible since iOS 11: https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/hack-for-hacker-news-reader/id1464477788

@sudoExclamationExclamation Mind you, in your code, you used UIAction, which is also available since iOS 13, and SnapKit, whose newest version requires iOS 12. I think you should probably post a new question, specifically asking how to do this in iOS 11, and remove things like UIAction so people don't get confused.

yea, the UIAction and SnapKit are just for easy demo purposes. My actual project isn't using them. It doesn't change the main problem.

Even if your current app is compatible with iOS 11, that isn't the question.  The question is are any of your users actually using iOS 11? - iOS 13 runs on the iPhone 6S and up - that is a phone released in 2015, so if you set your minimum support to iOS 13 you are cutting off 10+ year old devices.  Is that a significant part of your user base?

There are non-GCD options even for iOS 11. Combine is iOS 13+, but RxSwift can fit the bill with its debounce operator, made exactly for use cases like this.

@Alexander debounce filters things out though. OP wants all the requests to be sent eventually, but they should be sent "slowly". I don't know what the appropriate operator to use is.

@Sweeper True. In that case I think OP can use the zip operator with a timer. Also interesting: https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html

@Alexander I don't think zipping with a timer would meet the requirements either. When the user taps more slowly than once per 2 seconds, each request should be sent immediately. The timer would instead only send the request on multiples of 2 seconds, so in the worst case, the request has to wait for almost 2 seconds before getting sent.

Also, with zip, the timer will continue to add events to its observable when the user isn't doing anything. If the user then taps buttons quickly these will immediately be paired with these pending timer events and the api will be called more quickly. You can only solve this problem by putting the delay on the consumer side,  not on the publish side.

@Sweeper There's no need to explicitly break on Task.isCancelled because the for await does this behavior automatically, right?

@Paulw11 I know that I have many users running iOS 12 because I have received multiple emails from such users in the past on different issue.

Given that you want to support iOS 11, the native legacy pattern for managing dependencies between asynchronous operations would be a custom Operation subclass.
First, we would define a base class for our asynchronous operations:
/// Asynchronous Operation base class
///
/// This class performs all of the necessary KVC notifications of `isFinished` and
/// `isExecuting` for a concurrent `Operation` subclass. So, to develope
/// a concurrent `Operation` subclass, you instead subclass this class which:
///
/// - must override `main()` with the tasks that initiate the asynchronous task;
///
/// - must call `completeOperation()` function when the asynchronous task is done;
///
/// - optionally, periodically check `self.cancelled` status, performing any clean-up
///   necessary and then ensuring that `completeOperation()` is called; or
///   override `cancel` method, calling `super.cancel()` and then cleaning-up
///   and ensuring `completeOperation()` is called.

public class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {
    override public var isAsynchronous: Bool { true }

    private let stateLock = NSLock()

    private var _executing: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            stateLock.withLock { _executing }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
            stateLock.withLock { _executing = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isExecuting))
        }
    }

    private var _finished: Bool = false
    override private(set) public var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            stateLock.withLock { _finished }
        }
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
            stateLock.withLock { _finished = newValue }
            didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(isFinished))
        }
    }

    /// Complete the operation
    ///
    /// This will result in the appropriate KVN of isFinished and isExecuting

    public func completeOperation() {
        if isExecuting {
            isExecuting = false
        }

        if !isFinished {
            isFinished = true
        }
    }

    override public func start() {
        if isCancelled {
            isFinished = true
            return
        }

        isExecuting = true

        main()
    }

    override public func main() {
        fatalError("subclasses must override `main`")
    }
}

Once you have that, making an operation that performs a network request:
class DataOperation: AsynchronousOperation {
    private var dataTask: URLSessionTask?
    
    init(session: URLSession, request: URLRequest, networkCompletionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
        super.init()
        
        dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            networkCompletionHandler(data, response, error)
            self.completeOperation()
        }
    }

    override func main() {
       dataTask?.resume()
    }

    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()

        dataTask?.cancel()
    }

    override func completeOperation() {
        dataTask = nil

        super.completeOperation()
    }
}

And you can write one that performs the DataOperation, but delays the completion of the operation for two seconds:
class DataOperationWithDelay: DataOperation {
    let delay: TimeInterval
    
    init(session: URLSession, request: URLRequest, delay: TimeInterval, networkCompletionHandler: 
         @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
        self.delay = delay
        super.init(session: session, request: request, networkCompletionHandler: networkCompletionHandler)
    }
    
    override func completeOperation() {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            super.completeOperation()
        }
    }
}

Then you can add operations to your queue:
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

func start(request: URLRequest, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    let operation = DataOperationWithDelay(session: .shared, request: request, delay: 2) { data, response, error in
        // ... do whatever you want with the response here
        completion?()
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}

That would ensure that operations that you add to the queue will pause 2 seconds between network requests.
